# Apple's App Search API Validation Tool - "Error cannot fetch app site association"

Tags: ios, ios-universal-links

Im trying to get this [Apple's API validator](https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool) to validate my `apple-app-site-association` file on https://signin.methodwarehouse.com. The validator is saying "Error cannot fetch app site association". However, this file is clearly available at https://signin.methodwarehouse.com/apple-app-site-association. The content of this JSON file is copied directly from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016308-CH12-SW1) so it should validate just fine. What am I doing wrong? Why is this file not passing validationg?

[image: Screenshot of Apple's API Validator]

Answer (score 1):

This issue resolved by itself in a matter of a few hours. I think what happened was Apple's API validator was using a cached version of my `apple-appsite-association` file that was invalid.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue? I was faced with the same and universal links are not going to work for me.

Comment: I didn't do anything to resolve the issue. I eventually got the expected results by running the validation tool a few hours later.

Comment: I am facing same issue, still it is not resolved. What is the file extension, In notepad I saved as All Type files, where it save as text document only, is that fine?